# openid-configuration: No such host > is known

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-cli

I am seeing the following issue when I tried to run the login command.

> Error connecting to
> https://xc1id.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration: No such host
> is known.

[image]

I have tried to access the *openid-configuration* https://xc1id.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration. It is accessible. And, there is no issue when connecting to the identity server when I open cm. It is properly redirecting to the ID server, able to log in and redirect back to CM.

[image]

- Sitecore CLI : 3.0
- Sitecore XC 10.1 (Containers)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Able to resolve the issue.

`Missing host entry in host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc)`

`127.0.0.1 xc1id.localhost`

After adding this, it is resolved.